# Calculate number of acquired points given an input integer, size of levels, and points per level

Tags: php, algorithm, time-complexity, logic, formula

I have a task where I must calculate the number of "earned points" based on how many "levels" a value reaches.

Let's say that each level has a range of 5 increments.
In other words, if `$x = 5` that means:

- level 1 is 1,2,3,4,5 and
- level 2 is 6,7,8,9,10 and so on

Every time the input value (`$a`) enters a new level, 10 points (`$y = 10`) are earned.

If `$a` is `2`, this number falls in the first range, and therefore earns `10` points.
Furthermore, `$a = 5` earns `10`, `$a = 7` earns `20`, and `$a = 12` earns `30`.

I have written some code using a while loop, but I do not want to use a while loop due to the time complexity.

```
$a = 11;
$x = 5;
$y = 10;
$count = 100/$x;
$i = 1;
$c = 1 ;
while($i<=$count){
    $min = $c ;
    $max = $c = $c + ($x -1);
    if (in_array($a, range($min, $max))) {
        echo "\n result= " . $i * $y;
        break;
    }
    $c++;
    $i++;
}
```

Output of above code is correctly `30`, but I'd like to find a more efficient technique.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you want to add `y` for every range of `x` numbers till `a` starting from `1`. *If this assumption is correct*, you can divide `a` by `x` to get the offset(number of ranges that will occur) and multiply it by `y`. If division of `a / x` has decimals, increment the quotient(as in offset) by 1 before multiplying by `y`.

**Snippet:**

```
<?php

$tests = [
        2,
        5,
        7,
        11,
        12
    ];
    
$x = 5;
$y = 10;

foreach($tests as $a){
    $quo = intval($a / $x);
    if($quo * $x < $a) $quo++;
    echo $a," => " ,$quo * $y,PHP_EOL;
}
```

**Demo:** https://3v4l.org/rDe3Z

So, this way, time complexity is `O(1)`.

Answer (score 0):

I would simply use `ceil($a / $x) * $y` to calculate the total.  In plain English, divid the number by the points per level, then round that value up to the next whole integer, then multiply that value by the points per level.

I am assuming that negative inputs either aren't possible or should generate negative results.  I am also assuming that a zero input should have a zero output.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/aJWuY))

```
$as = [0, 1, 2, 5, 7, 10, 16, 49];
$x = 5;
$y = 10;
foreach ($as as $a) {
    echo "$a => " . (ceil($a / $x) * $y) . "\n";
}
```

Output:

```
0 => 0
1 => 10
2 => 10
5 => 10
7 => 20
10 => 20
16 => 40
49 => 100
```